# How can I get all tables names of a schema?

Tags: java, jdbc

How can I get all tables names of a schema? I have tried this:

```
DatabaseMetaData metaData = (DatabaseMetaData) conn.getMetaData();
metaData.getTables(null, schema, null, null);
```

but it does not work.

Finally I have made this:

```
conn.setCatalog(mySchema);
String sqlQuery = "show tables";
rs = ps.executeQuery(sqlQuery); 
while (rs.next())
{
   System.out.print(rs.getString(1));
}
```

Comment: Which database? It is entirely possible that what you think is the schema, is actually the catalog in JDBC terms.

Comment: the database is MySQL

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
ResultSet tables = metaData.getTables(null, null, null, new String[] {"TABLE"});
while (tables.next()){
    System.out.print(tables.getString("TABLE_NAME") + " ");
}
```

EDIT: Second parameter is where you specify the schema pattern (e.g. "Sales"), null for all schemas.

Comment: I think this works with all vendors. When the user does not match with the schema, you should avoid specifying the schema in some vendors. This behavior depend on the implementation of the driver.

Comment: and Is not necessary to use the schema name? because my data base has several schemas

Comment: No, it's not necessary. Schema name is used to narrow down the search.

Comment: That is my case, I need to narrow down by the schema, in this case, is this correct?                                               metaData.getTables(null, mySchema, null, new String[] {"TABLE"});         the second param is schemaPattern

Comment: Yes, but, as Paul Vargas wrote, you should avoid specifying the schema in some DBMS.

Comment: It is better to use `"%"` for the `tablePattern` parameter if you want all tables. The JDBC spec isn't entirely clear if `null` is allowed for it, some drivers consider `null` as an invalid value for that parameter and yield no results, other drivers behave as if `"%"` was passed.

Answer (score 4):

Try the following:

```
DatabaseMetaData metaData = (DatabaseMetaData) conn.getMetaData();
ResultSet rs = metaData.getTables(null, null, "%", null);
while (rs.next()) {
  System.out.println(rs.getString(3));
}
```

The [documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/sql/DatabaseMetaData.html#getTables%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%5B%5D%29) says that the third column is **TABLE_NAME**.

Answer (score 2):

For mysql:5.6 -

To get particular tables of a particular schema, I have to pass the *schema name* as *"catalog"* parameter(1st param). It was ignoring, if  I pass it as *"schemaPattern"* parameter( 2nd param).

I assumed that it has to do with the fact that "create schema' is a synonym for "create database" in mysql. 
https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/create-database.html

```
DatabaseMetaData meta = (DatabaseMetaData) 

support.getConnection().getMetaData();
    rs = meta.getTables("schema_name", null, null, new String[] { "TABLE" });
    while (rs.next()) {
        String tblName = rs.getString("TABLE_NAME");
        System.out.println(tblName);
    }
```